# Timedelta without Date

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a column with times that are not timestamps and would like to know the timedelta to 00:30:00 o'clock. However, I can only find methods for timestamps.

```
df['Time'] = ['22:30:00', '23:30:00', '00:15:00']
```

The intended result should look something like this:

```
df['Output'] = ['02:00:00', '01:00:00', '00:15:00']
```

Comment: What is the dtype of `df['Time']`?

Comment: I used pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time but I'm open to any changes.

Comment: Add virtual date to it, maybe? Like... (today+this time) minus (today+00:30) == this time minus 00:30. Or you can just make a function to do it manually since timedelta keeps days and seconds, so you'd need to convert it to desired format anyways + 00:15 has diff without minus?

Comment: My question is *what shows `df['Time'].dtype`?* ...

Comment: Strangely, all dtypes say 'O'.

Comment: Probably the 'O' means that the data is in the form of Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code convert a type of Time value from `str` to `datetime` (`date` is automatically set as 1900-01-01). Then, calculated `timedelta` by setting standardTime as 1900-01-02-00:30:00.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Time'] = ['22:30:00', '23:30:00', '00:15:00']

standardTime = datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 30, 0)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['Output'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: standardTime-x).astype(str).str[7:] # without astype(str).str[7:], the Output value include a day such as "0 days 01:00:00"

print(df)

#                 Time    Output
#0 1900-01-01 22:30:00  02:00:00
#1 1900-01-01 23:30:00  01:00:00
#2 1900-01-01 00:15:00  00:15:00
```

Comment: you can simplify to `(pd.Timestamp("1900-01-02 00:30")-df['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 1):

One could want to use `datetime.time` as data structures, but these cannot be subtracted, so you can't conveniently get a `timedelta` from them.

On the other hand, `datetime.datetime` objects can be subtracted, so if you're always interested in positive deltas, you could construct a `datetime` object from your time representation using `1970-01-01` as date, and compare that to `1970-01-02T00:30`.

For instance, if your times are stored as strings (as per your snippet):

```py
import datetime as dt

def timedelta_to_0_30(time_string: str) -> dt.timedelta:
    time_string_as_datetime = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(f"1970-01-01T{time_string}")
    return dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 30) - time_string_as_datetime

my_time_string = "22:30:00"
timedelta_to_0_30(my_time_string)  # 2:00:00
```